# is it possible to authenticate in a springboot app using the different oracle accounts

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I'm developing a web application and I'm wondering if i can set the authentication to check the oracle users instead of a user table I that I manually make.

Basically I want this to make it easier to trace user activities using oracle's native logs and add an extra layer to manage permissions.

Comment: Could be possible by implementing a custom [AuthenticationProvider](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.5.x/api/org/springframework/security/authentication/AuthenticationProvider.html) BUT it won't be easily possible to use different database users for the actual database connection your app uses…

Comment: thank you, I'll read up on that but do you have any suggestion on the best way to handle this if there is a way other than making a custom log service ?

Comment: I'm not aware of any solution that wouldn't require custom code.

Comment: understood thank you, custom code it is then